# SQLAlchemy constraints not visible in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgadmin

I am trying to add constraints to my database (PostGreSQL, on Amazon RDS).

My code:

```
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{AWS_RDS_USER}:{AWS_RDS_PASSWORD}@{AWS_RDS_ENDPOINT}:{AWS_RDS_PORT}/{DBNAME}')
    
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("ALTER TABLE hotel ADD CONSTRAINT pk_hotel_id PRIMARY KEY (hotel_id);"))
```

There is no problem with the connection to the database as I manage to load data to the tables without problem.

However, the constraints I create are not visible in pgAdmin.

Can you please help ?

Regards,

I'm expecting to see the constraints in pgAdmin

Comment: I am not seeing where you `commit` the transaction. Without a `commit` the changes will not persist nor will they be seen by other sessions. See [Commit]https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.commit) for more information.